# 2 magnet bars are placed in same plane and one of them can rotate freely. The relation as system is balanced

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, mathematical-physics, magnetic-moment

[image]

Each magnet is in same plane.

$$ \ell \ll r $$

The magnet1 has been fixed.

The magnet2 can rotate with center of the magnet itself.

$$  \theta_{1} ~~,~~ \theta_{2} :=\text{each angle between the middle line as balanced}  $$

$~ H_{2r} ,~ H_{2 \theta_{} }:=\text{magnetic field vectors made by magnet1}   ~$

As the system is balanced , directions of magnet2($~ M_{2} ~$ ) and the magnetic field $~ H_{2}  ~$ are same.

**Claim 1**
$$  \tan \left( \phi_{}  \right) = \frac{  H_{\theta_{} }   }{  H_{r}   } =\frac{1}{2} \tan \left( \theta_{1}  \right) \tag{1}   $$

**Claim 2**

From the diagram, $~ \phi_{} =-\theta_{2}  ~$ is held at balanced position.

Currently I can't get each claim stated above.

Which website(s) should I refer??

Comment: Are you given formulas for $H_r$ and $H_{\theta}$?

Comment: No. It weren't given.

Comment: I don't think this is true for all fields. It must depend on some property of the dipole field.

Comment: I added the condition $~1 \ll r~$

Comment: The condition $1 \ll r$ is dimensionally inconsistent and therefore meaningless because $r$ is a length measured eg in units of metres and $1$ is a pure number with no units. Perhaps you mean that $r$ is much greater than the length of each magnet?

Comment: @sammygerbil Yes. How should I have written about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition $1 \ll r$ is dimensionally inconsistent and therefore meaningless because $r$ is a length measured eg in units of metres and $1$ is a pure number with no units. I think you mean that $\ell \ll r$ where $\ell$ is the largest dimension of magnet M1.

Close to the magnets where $r  \sim \ell$ the magnetic field depends significantly on the shape of the magnets. At large distances from the magnets where $r \gg \ell$ the magnetic field has the same form as that from an **electric dipole** :
$$H_r=2P\cos\theta$$ $$H_{\theta}=P\sin\theta$$
where $$P=\frac{p}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^3}$$
See eqns #3 in [this link](https://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/%7Emevans/em/lec5.pdf) and Slide 6 in [this link](http://www.cbpf.br/%7Eieeemag/lectures/Jander_I.pdf).

From the above equations you can derive claim #1.

Magnet M2 is stable when the magnetic field $H_2$ at M2 due to M1 points along the direction of M2. Then $\phi = -\theta_2$ which proves claim #2.

Comment: I got claim #1. But I've been in trouble of proving claim #2 .

Comment: I have to go to work from now so I will post my thoughts later.

Comment: Claim #2 is easier. Angle $\phi$ is measured anti-clockwise from $H_{2r}$ to $H_2$. Turn $H_2$ clockwise. When $H_2$ points along $H_{2r}$ then $\phi=0$.  When $H_2$ points along $M_2$ then $\phi=-\theta_2$.